# Visual Studio 2019 v16.2.1 can't open sql script file in SSDT project

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed the latest Visual Studio 2019. I can open my SQL database project. But when I try to open a SQL script file, I got the error:

```
Failed to create an editor. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Password.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

delete the file with "user" extension in your application root.

Comment: I don't have a .User file in my project folder at all.

Comment: Bill, You won't see the .user file in Visual Studio, but in the root folder in Windows File Explorer (i.e. *.sqlproj.user).

Comment: buggy visual studio. Thanks for saving me.

Comment: Still relevant with Visual Studio 2022 [Enterprise] Version 17.5.1

Comment: Great info. If you do this while VS is open, you will probably need to restart the app because the contents of this file are cached on load.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me too when I had a connection setup in my database project, where the password is blank.

Even though the database server I use is perfectly fine with no password, the editor in Visual Studio is not able to handle this.

For me as a workaround, I use another connection for my development process. If you can't do that, I recommend creating a new user for this purpose - where the password is set.